# Etherscan API Invalid API key

Tags: etherscan

I created an account on etherscan, navigate to the API Keys settings in the user panel, and added a key. I go to the API documentation, take any API call, insert my API key, and I get an invalid API key response. Do I need to link my wallet to etherscan, or go through some other verification process? I have tried creating new keys, several API endpoints on ropsten and mainnet, and they all fail with the same Invalid API key response.

If there is some other information I can provide, I would be happy to. The only information I can think of is my API key. I have tried various endpoints, here are two of them.

https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=transaction&action=getstatus&txhash=0x15f8e5ea1079d9a0bb04a4c58ae5fe7654b5b2b4463375ff7ffb490aa0032f3a&apikey=YourApiKeyToken

https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=stats&action=ethsupply&apikey=YourApiKeyToken

The end goal here is to verify a test contract on ropsten.

Answer (score 15):

I had this problem. The API Key seems to take about five minutes to activate once it is created.

Comment: This was the case for me as well!

Answer (score 3):

I think I may have just been using the API during a scheduled maintenance window. Checking things this morning and everything is fine.

https://info.etherscan.com/psa-scheduled-server-maintenance-and-upgrades-1st-may-2020-1-30-am-gmt-0/

Endpoints are working, and I Was able to verify my contract using `curl -d "address=MY_CONTRACT_ADDRESS" "https://api-ropsten.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=verifyproxycontract&apikey=MY_API_KEY"`